# MFC CSrollView Zoom

Tags: mfc

I have a CViewIamge class that is derived from the CScrollView. Displaying images on a picture control on CDialog derived dialog. How can I add zoom in capability?. Currently using SetDIBitsToDevice in the OnDraw.

Comment: May not give ideal quality but using `StretchDIBits()` would be a simple substitution for what you currently do.

Comment: I have picture control and CMyView is derived from CScrollView. Within CMyCiew::OnDraw(CDC *pDC), i was calling SetDIBitsToDevice.
With StretchDIBits this does not work,  no picture.why?.How to make it work?.

Comment: Within CMyCiew::OnDraw(CDC *pDC) replaced SetDIBitsToDevice simply with StretchDIBits. Now, it does not work,  no image.why?.How to make it work?.